# Compatibility of protobuf-c and protobuf

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers, ethernet

Working on a project which has client and server ***can I use*** protobuf-c on the client side for packing, and use protobuf(official C++ version) on the server side to unpack it? Are they compatible to use?
After packing using protobuf-c (unofficial) on the client side, and unpacking on the server side using official C++, Google API returns failed status (API parse from array).

Comment: So do you have a minimal example which demonstrates the problem, including the data that the protobuf-c code emits? It should be fairly easy to determine whether or not it's valid.

Comment: what is protobuf?Protocol Buffers?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. Google protobuf was exactly invented to cover this situation. BTW, for the c side I would recommend nano-pb, if you have a limited platform.

Comment: @AliRezaJafari Yes it's a common synonym.

Comment: Were you able to fix your errors?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, you can.**

A big chunk of the entire purpose of Protocol Buffers is that there is an API that you can use to pass data between different systems, even if those systems are not written in the same programming language.

It does not matter one bit whether you use a C++ client, or a C client, or a Python client, or a Go client, or a JavaScript client, or a client constructed on a giant abacus in the middle of the desert: compatibility is guaranteed by the fact that these are implementations of an API.